# Lenz's Law for Moving Loops

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, inductance, lenz-law

[image]

This image above intrigued me since it shows different instances of Lenz's Law. I am learning about magnetic fields, but I get confused on the direction of induced magnetic fields. I was wondering what would happen if I moved the loop towards the magnet instead for each of these scenarios, would it be the same as the magnet moving? For instance, focus on b,c,d,e in particular. If I moved the loop towards the magnet, would the flux/induced current directions be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, moving the magnet down or moving the coil up will yield the same result.